# Boyer Moore implementation c++

Tags: c++, boyer-moore

http://igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/string/node14.html#SECTION00140

I don't know what that function: "OUTPUT(j)" mean, can anybody help me? And the function MAX()?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: `OUTPUT(j)` means report the index `j` of the found match in whatever way you need, write it to the console, to an array, whatever. `MAX()` gets the maximum of two numbers.

Answer (score 1):

`MAX` is just `std::max` (exists in C++ but not in C; that page is C code).

`OUTPUT(j)` you have to provide, to do something when a match is found.

Comment: I found this page that implements Boyer Moore too, but I need both implementation: boyermoore1() and boyermoore2() in the same function.

Comment: http://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/algoritmos/aulas/strma.html